# how to sniff out mac adresses 5 miles from my location

Tags: internet-explorer-8

i would like to know what program i would need to sniff out a mac address 5 miles from my location
can anyone help me
many thanx
keith

Comment: -1: Doesn't make sense. At all...

Comment: You lay 5 miles of CAT5 down back to the network's router.

Answer (score 3):

The MAC address of a machine is visible only to the local network. Therefore, you need to have access to that LAN by being on it or being able to run software on a machine that is on it.

Comment: @keith: Precisely, learn about the OSI model before you start trying anything more complicated with networking.